# comparing a number within a range in an if statement

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make an if statement that takes the text of a textField (texto) and find if that number is within a range, here I put the code I have written, there is a mistake for sure in the condition when I extract the number from the textField text, can someone tell me what is the proper way to write this line of code?

```
if ((texto.text>=1)&&(texto.text>=5)) {
    tabViewController *vc2;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `>=` on one side and `<=` on the other side, and also call `intValue` before comparison, like this:

```
if ([texto.text intValue] >=1 && [texto.text intValue] <= 5) {
    ...
}
```